# 2.2.3 Elastic Search option missing in Admin console

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, elasticsearch

Magento CE 2.2.3 release notes says Support has been added for Elasticsearch 5.x

After installing and configuring Elastic Search I cannot work out how to have this option available in the admin console.

It should show up under Stores > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search > Search Engine

At the moment only MySQL is available.

Answer (score 3):

**That means now we can Use Elasticsearch software version 5.x with magento 2.2.3**

in previous version we can only use **Elasticsearch software version 2.x**

**But that does't mean , they have added Magento 2 Elasticsearch(Commerce) module in Open Source(Community Version)**

**Its still only available with Commerce Version (Enterprise Version).**

> **So based on the release notes of open Source 2.2.3 - Now onwards if you installed any third party elasticsearch extension, you can use
>   Elasticsearch Software version 5.X with it.**

To check the difference refer this 2.1 release notes link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

To check the difference refer this 2.2 release notes link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.3CE.html

**UPDATE :**

**Magento has updated release notes and remove that elastic search support note from open source 2.2.3 here is the link** -http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.3CE.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in the Release Note. If you are looking for ES support you have to options :

- Go with Magento Commerce (Enterprise)
- Go with ElasticSuite (https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite)

Comment: I thought it was too good to be true. I note the release notes have now changed.

Comment: Yep. I ask for v the change in the doc

Comment: The release note have been fixed.
Maybe can you mark the question responded.